Proving there is a Epimorphism that Splits.
Let be $R$ a ring, $\varphi:M_{1}\to M_{2}$ a isomorphism beetwen $R$-modules, $\xi_{1}:P_{1}\to M_{1}$ a epimorphism with $P_{1}$ projective and $\xi_{2}:P_{2}\to M_{2}$ a projective cover.
Show that $\exists~\psi:P_{1}\to P_{2}$ an epimorphism such splits and $\xi_{2}\circ \psi=\varphi\circ \xi_{1}$.

Following the proof in "Modules and Rings" of Kash, this is what I've write:
Lets consider the homomorphism $\varphi\circ \xi_{1}:P_{1}\to M_{2}$, since $\xi_{2}$ is an epimorphism and $P_{1}$ is projective, there is $\psi:P_{1}\to P_{2}$ an homomorphism such $\xi_{2}\circ\psi=\varphi\circ \xi_{1}$. Clearly $\varphi\circ \xi_{1}$ is and epimorphism since $\varphi$ and $\xi_{1}$ are epimorphism. So in that way $P_{2}=\text{Im}(\psi)+\text{Ker}(\xi_{2})$.
In the other hand, $\xi_{2}$ is a projective cover, so then $\xi_{2}$ is superfluous and $\text{Ker}(\xi_{2})\ll M$, so $\text{Im}(\psi)=P_{2}$. This is, $\psi$ is and epimorphism. Also $P_{2}$ is projective, and then $\exists~\phi:P_{2}\to P_{1}$ a homomorphism such $\varphi\circ\xi_{1}\circ\phi=\xi_{2}$. Finally,
$$\varphi\circ \xi_{1}\circ \phi=\xi_{2}\circ \psi\circ \phi=\xi_{2}$$
And now I would to conclude that $\psi\circ \phi=\text{Id}_{P_{2}}$, but cancellation works only if $\xi_{2}$ is a monomorphism. So, what's wrong?

Every epimorphism onto a projective module splits, so $\psi$ splits.
This is standard. If $\psi:X\to P$ is an epimorphism with $P$ projective, then we can lift the identity map on $P$ to a map $\phi:P\to X$, giving $\psi\circ\phi=1_P$.
In your case this then gives $\varphi\circ\xi_1\circ\phi=\xi_2\circ\psi\circ\phi=\xi_2$, but as you’ve realized, not every $\phi$ satisfying the latter equality gives a section.
